# Upgrading create react app to version 4 gives : ReferenceError: Cannot access 'middleware' before initialization

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, webpack-dev-server, react-scripts

I tried upgrading react scripts to 4.0.1 and type script to "4.1.3" and react to "17.0.1". I deleted the node_modules and lock files, then installed again with yarn install command. When I run yarn start,
I get error `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'middleware' before initialization`

[image]

When I set FAST_REFRESH=false in .env file app loads with no issues, So it is something with react refresh

Comment: Would you please share a screenshot of the error?

Comment: updated with screenshot

Comment: Please post text, not images of text.

Comment: When I set FAST_REFRESH=false in .env file app loads with no issues, So it is something with react refresh

Comment: Any help here is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

It's a known issue https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9904. It has to do with a change in Create React App. Fast Refresh, or React Refresh is about to replace Hot Reload. By default `FAST_REFRESH` is set to `true`.

For now I stick to Hot Reload, by setting `FAST_REFRESH=false` as you did and track the issue given above.